# Erro to call a controller - Codeignither

Tags: php, codeigniter

I beginner with codeigniter and i have a project in my localhost when i tried to call the controller the system displayed the following error

**Severidad: Warning
Mensaje: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Error' does not have a method 'index'
Nombre del archivo: core/CodeIgniter.php
Número de línea: 359**

**I call from a menu with this part of view:**

`<li><?php echo anchor("administrador_casos_controller/reasignacion_casos_ctrl", ' <i class="fa fa-retweet" ></i> <span>Reasignación de casos <br/>por agente</span>'); ?>` `</li>`

**On my controller recive it in this way:**

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Reasignacion_casos extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->sesion_model->ValidarSesion();
        $this->rol_sistema=array("administrador_casos");    
        $this->id_usuario=$this->session->userdata("sava_idusuario");
        $this->sesion_model->ValidarRolUsuario( $this->id_usuario,$this->rol_sistema);
        $this->load->model("m_reasignacion_casos_agente");
    }
    

    function index(){

        $data['titulo']="Administrador Casos | Reasignación de Tickets por agente";
        $data['contenido'] = $this->load->view("reportes/reasignacion_casos_agente/reasignacion_casos_agente","", TRUE);
        $this->load->view('v_principal', $data);

    }}
```

But the view not send to the controller, could you help me about this issue?

Thanks

Comment: you need to provide a little bit more information on your `call_user_func_array()` method, which needs to have *parameter 1 set to be a valid callback*... that is what the error says

Comment: @Julian have you checked the rendered output or generated source code in the browser to see what `archor()` is providing?  Is the path correct? Have you checked the routing?

Comment: Hi mickmackusa, thanks for your response, about that you told, yes, the path is correct, we used with other pages on the same project and working

Comment: Thanks Vickel, i review it, but nothing works, i don´t sure what parameter should be provide